# Event observer method calling service methods?

Tags: java, events, transactions

OK, what I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

In a java enterprise bean I want to move a file to a different directory unless a database operation fails (namely, I want to store the correct location of the file in the database. Now if something went wrong within the transaction and it's rolled back, my database points to a wrong location for the file if I already moved the file. Not good.).

I tried to fire an event with an observing method using the transaction phase AFTER_SUCCESS to move the file. So far so good. But the file move could also fail (maybe I don't have access to the target directory or something like that) and I want to write that failure into the data base as well. Unfortunately it seems like the observer method does not provide me with a transaction and my method call fails.

Is the idea of calling a service method from the observing method a bad one? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should work with transactional resource firstly and then with non-transactional. The reason is that you can roll-back transactional resource but you cannot roll-back non transactional one.

I mean: if you was able to update row in database and then trying to move file and it fails, you can safely roll-back database update. But, if you moving file and it success, but you cannot update database for some reason - you cannot roll-back moved file.

In your particular case I would suggest to not actually move the file, but copy it instead. So that in database you will always have actual location of new copy. And in different thread you can delete old copies somehow. You need to use copies because `IOException` can be thrown when actual file was moved and when you rollback transaction in database you will end up with wrong old location. Try to use this approach (using `EJB` container-managed transactions; you can safely find Spring variant of that):

```
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
void move(String newLocation, int fileId) throws CouldNotMoveException, DatabaseException {
    try {
        database.updateFileLocation(fileId, newLocation);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new DatabaseException(exc);
    }
    try {
        file.copyFile(fileId, newLocation);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        throw new CouldNotMoveException(exc);
    }
}
```

You will need to create your exceptions like this in order to rollback your transactions (or just use `RuntimeException` - check documentation on your container about reacting to exception and rollback policies):

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class DatabaseException extends Exception {
// omited
}

@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class CouldNotMoveException extends Exception {
// omited
}
```

Here you client code can react on `CouldNotMoveException` and write the wrong move in database so you will fullfil your requirements.

Comment: The idea with copying the file instead of moving might solve my problem here. I have to look into it, even if it looks somewhat awkward (but that's just an aesthetic problem and much better than an inconsistent database obviously). The real problem with your solution (for my case) is the manual transaction handling. I would really rather not do that since it's the responsibility of the container/hibernate to do that.

Comment: @PeterFrisch I edited my answer. You can rewrite my example with container managed transactions. It was provided only for clear understanding of what is going on.

Comment: I would like to accept the answer. It seems like I can't do that yet ... But thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: @PeterFrisch that's no problem. I just want to add that you need to be care with `Transaction Propagation` strategies. If client of you method is participating in transaction then if you rollback it inside of the method you cannot do database update about wrong moved file because transaction will be already rollback. May be use `REQUIRES_NEW` propogation instead.